# Flutter child is hiding under another child when it is not placed in a stack widget

Tags: flutter, dart, widget

I tried to put the container with a text outside of the Stack child but it still goes under the other children in stack. How should I fix this?

```
    import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

    class StoreFront extends StatefulWidget {
      @override
      _StoreFrontState createState() => _StoreFrontState();
    }

    class _StoreFrontState extends State<StoreFront> {
      @override
      Widget build(BuildContext context) {
        return Container(
          height: 150,
          child: ListView(
            scrollDirection: Axis.horizontal,
            children: <Widget>[
              Container(
                margin: EdgeInsets.only(bottom: 10.0),
                height: 80.0,
                child: Stack(
                  children: <Widget>[
                    Container(
                      height: 800,
                      width: 370,
                      decoration: BoxDecoration(borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(Radius.circular(250.0))),
                      child: Image(
                          image: AssetImage("assets/images/newlookfront.png"),
                        fit: BoxFit.fill,
                      ),
                    ),
                    Positioned(
                      bottom: 60,
                      left: 65.0,
                      child: Row(
                        children: <Widget>[
                          Text("NEW LOOK", style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white70, fontSize: 35.0),)
                        ],
                      ),
                    ),
                  ],
                ),
              ),
              Container(
                child: Row(
                  children: <Widget>[
                    Text("New Look")
                  ],
                ),
              ),
            ],
          ),
        );
      }
    }
```

Comment: Take a look at this https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/ExcludeSemantics-class.html

Answer (score 0):

I tested your code.

```
Container(
    height: 150,
    child: ListView(
      scrollDirection: Axis.horizontal,
      children: <Widget>[
        Container(
          margin: EdgeInsets.only(bottom: 10.0),
          height: 80.0,
          child: Stack(
            alignment: Alignment.center,
            children: <Widget>[
              Container(
                height: 800,
                width: 370,
                decoration: BoxDecoration(borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(Radius.circular(250.0))),
                child: Image(
                  image: AssetImage("assets/images/intro_0.jpg"),
                  fit: BoxFit.fill,
                ),
              ),
              Container(
                child: Row(
                  children: <Widget>[
                    Text("New Look")
                  ],
                ),
              ),
              Positioned(
                bottom: 60,
                left: 65.0,
                child: Row(
                  children: <Widget>[
                    Text("NEW LOOK", style: TextStyle(color: Colors.cyan, fontSize: 35.0),)
                  ],
                ),
              ),
            ],
          ),
        ),
      ],
    ),
  )
```

The widgets in stack's children are displayed in the order of writing. The stack has the first widget as its size, and the widgets added thereafter are superimposed on the top layer in turn.

[image: Code screenshot]